# Can't install packages with renv on docker container (rocker/verse:3.6.3): permission denied on staged install

Tags: docker, rstudio, renv

I'm trying to use renv with docker using the `rocker/verse:3.6.3` image. I get an error "permission denied" on package install upon moving files from staging to library directory. I tried to disable staged installation using both `options(renv.config.install.staged = FALSE)` and `options(renv.config.install.transactional = FALSE)`, also tried via environment variables--`Sys.setenv(RENV_CONFIG_INSTALL_STAGED = FALSE)`, `Sys.setenv(RENV_CONFIG_INSTALL_TRANSACTIONAL = FALSE)`--with no luck. Any idea on something I'm missing &/or potential workaround?

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile?

Comment: I'm running docker run directly in a bash script with environment variables: 
`docker run --rm \
  -e DISABLE_AUTH=${DISABLE_AUTH} -e ROOT=${ROOT} -e "RENV_PATHS_CACHE=${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER}" \
  -e "RENV_CONFIG_CACHE_ENABLED=${RENV_CONFIG_CACHE_ENABLED}" -e "RENV_CONFIG_INSTALL_TRANSACTIONAL=${RENV_CONFIG_INSTALL_TRANSACTIONAL}" \
  -v "${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_HOST}:${RENV_PATHS_CACHE_CONTAINER}" -v ${PROJECT_DIR_MOUNT} \
  -p ${PORT_MAP} --name rstudio ${IMAGE}`